# Why we have to set the relations of the database at model and migration? Adonis JS

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, adonis.js

Why is needed at Adonis.js set the relationship that exists at a database on Migrations (with reference) and at Models (with hasMany)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In summary, migrations and models are independent and do not work together. To use the models it's not necessary to use migrations (you can use an existing database).*

### Migrations

Migrations are used to create the db.

You have to define the structure of the db in the migration files. So relationships are important.

From [official documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/migrations#sponsor) :

> Migrations are documented database mutations, created throughout your application’s development lifecycle that you can roll back or re-run at any point in time.
>
> Migrations make it easier to work as a team, enabling database schema changes from one developer to be easily tracked and then applied by other developers in your organization.

Of course, it's not necessary to use migration. You can create your own db and use only the [models](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#sponsor) that allow you to retrieve the data.

### [Models - Relationships](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships)

The interesting thing about models (Lucid) is that it's easy to make SQL queries (with Knex).

Since models and migrations are not linked, it's necessary to declare the different relationships between the tables you are going to use.

Lucid is the AdonisJS implementation of the [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).

From [official documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships):

> Relationships are the backbone of data-driven applications, linking one model type to another.
>
> For example, a User could have many Post relations, and each Post could have many Comment relations.
>
> Lucid’s expressive API makes the process of associating and fetching model relations simple and intuitive, without the need to touch a SQL statement or even edit a SQL schema.

#### Example :

Relations :

[image: Adonis models - relations]

User model :

```js
const Model = use('Model')

class User extends Model {
  posts () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Post') // has many Post
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

Controller code :

```js
const User = use('App/Models/User')

const users = await User
  .query()
  .with('posts') // Use model relationship
  .fetch()
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    username: 'virk',
    posts: [{
      id: 1,
      user_id: 1,
      post_title: '...',
      post_body: '...',
    }]
  }
]
```

^ [Source](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_eager_loading)